# Highchart object not support removeAttribute and Y axis label is not aligned [Internet Explorer 8]

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts

```
here it code

    $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    showAxes : true,
                    type: 'line',
            spacingBottom: 50,
            style: {
                   fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                 }
                },
                tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var colors = new Array("#3dcd50","#feb421","#e5928a");
                            var quarterArray = new Array ("Jan-Mar","Apr-Jun","Jul-Sep","Oct-Dec");
                            var prefix ="";

                            var p = new Date(this.x);
                            var year = p.getFullYear();var month = p.getMonth();

                            if ( month >= 1 && month <= 3 ){
                            prefix = quarterArray[0];
                            }
                            else if ( month >= 4 && month <= 6 ){
                                    prefix = quarterArray[1];
                            }
                            else if ( month >= 7 && month <= 9 ){
                                    prefix = quarterArray[2];
                            }
                            else if ( month >= 10 && month <= 12 ){
                                    prefix = quarterArray[3];
                            }
                            prefix += " "+year;

                            var str = '<table><tr><td><span style="color:grey;font-family=Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">'+ prefix+'</span><br/></td></tr>';
                            var i = 0;
                    var length = this.points.length;
                while ( i < length ){
                    str += '<tr><td><span style="color:'+colors[i]+'">'+this.points[i].series.name+' : </span></td>';
                    str += '<td style="text-align: right"><span style="font-size: 16px;font-family: WebRupee;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;" >Rs.</span><b> '+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.points[i].y, 0,'',',')+' /Sq.ft.</b><br/></td></tr>' ;     
                    i++;

                }
                                      str += '</table>';
                            return str;
                 },
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
             },
             borderColor: '#bfbfbf',
             backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
                    crosshairs: [true],
                    shared : true
                 },
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                type :'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    month: '%b'
                 },
                showFirstLabel: true,
                gridLineWidth : 0,
                tickInterval : 12*30*24*3600* 1000,
                tickLength : 20,
                tickWidth : 1,
                minorGridLineWidth : 0,
                minorTickInterval : 3*30*24 * 3600 * 1000 + 1.25*24 * 3600 * 1000,  //distributing 6 extra days in 4 quarters
                minorTickLength : 10,
                minorTickWidth : 1,
                lineWidth : 4,
                lineColor:'#e8e8e8',
                min : Date.UTC(2010,0, 1),
                max : Date.UTC(2013,6, 1),
                labels : {
                    align: 'center',
                    x: 53,
                    y: 30,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '12px',
                            fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
                      } 
                }
                },
                yAxis: {
            showFirstLabel: false,
            gridLineColor: '#e3e3e3',
                    title: {
                enabled : true,
                        text: 'PRICE <span style="font-family: WebRupee;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;" >Rs.</span> / SQ.FT.',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                    color : '#000000'
                } 
                    },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                   return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0,'',',');
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
                } 
            },
            min : 1241,
            max : 4400,
                    lineWidth: 4,
            lineColor:'#e8e8e8',
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 40,
                    borderWidth: 0,
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#000000',
                fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
            }
                },
              plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010,0, 45),
                        pointInterval : 3*30*24*3600* 1000 + 1.25*24 * 3600 * 1000
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Upper Range',
                    color : 'grey',
                    lineWidth : 1,
            connectNulls: true,
                    data: [1926,1931,1920,1912,1924,1947,2019,2516,2924,2648,2923,3119,3190,3400,null,null],
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#3dcd50',
                    lineWidth : 1,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius : 3,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fillColor:'#3dcd50',
                    lineWidth : 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'Average Range',
                    color : 'black',
            connectNulls: true,
                    lineWidth : 2,
                    data: [1826,1825,1820,1812,1810,1826,1919,2387,2440,2484,2787,3000,3048,3100,null,null],
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#feb421',
                        lineColor: '#feb421',
                        lineWidth : 2,
                symbol: 'circle',   
                radius : 5,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fillColor:'#ff6700',
                    lineWidth : 2
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }, {
                    name: 'Lower Range',
                    color : 'grey',
                    lineWidth : 1,
            connectNulls: true,
                    data: [1726,1725,1720,1712,1710,1726,1810,2281,2325,2346,2663,2861,2948,2989,null,null],
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#e5928a',
                    lineWidth : 1,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius : 3,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fillColor:'#e5928a',
                    lineWidth : 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });    
});
```

you can see this in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QGNT3/
This is working fine in chrome,safari,firefox,IE9 & IE10 but for IE 8 , there are few errors
1) Y axis label is not vertically aligned 
2) Object not support property of method "removeAttribute" whiling clicking on legends and hovering the series
3) not rendering the series line color [ rendering black ]

Comment: I opened your example in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/QGNT3/show/ (becasuse jsfiddle.net is not compability with IE8, so http://jsfiddle.net/QGNT3/ will generate errors) and all works properly. Which version of IE8 do you havE ?

Answer (score 0):

- Try to clear the cache of IE8
- Try to update the Jquery to the version supported by IE8

Answer (score 0):

1) && 3) - works for me perfectly, see image: [image: ie8]

2) Remove extra comma, see fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/QGNT3/1/ (`fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',` <-- here)